# Trouble opening .dat file

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, output, ifstream

**Having a hard time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong when trying to open "test.dat" file. It seems to be opening it, but not reading it to give output. The program is supposed to read the frequency of numbers.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
string fileName;
int aTest;

cout << "Enter a File Name: ";
cin >> fileName;

ifstream inFile (fileName.c_str());
if (! inFile)
{
cout << "!!Error in opening file 'test.dat'"<< endl;
}

vector<int> test(101, 0); 
while(inFile >> aTest) {
test[aTest]++;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**The test.dat file**

```
75  85   90  100  
60  90  100   85
75  35   60   90
100 90   90   90
60  50   70   85
75  90   90   70
```

**This is how my output looks right now**

```
Enter a File Name: test.dat
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**The way it's suppose to look**

```
Enter file name: test.dat
100: 3
90: 8
85: 3
75: 3
70: 2
60: 3
50: 1
35: 1
```

Comment: Your program looks fine, but you don't print anything out, so why do you expect that output?

Comment: Ummmm, how about you display the contents of the array after reading the values in...

Comment: @newbie, what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @CarlNorum, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't attempt to print anything out, so it's no surprise there's no output.  Add a loop and print out the non-zero entries:

```
for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (test[i])
    {
        cout << i << ": " << test[i] << endl;
    }
}
```